# ¿Como puedo mostrar los comentarios de un post en Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

estoy bastante verde todavia con esto, y a medida que fui avanzando con el blog me encontre con un problema a la hora de poder mostrar los comentarios de un post, este es mi codigo, se les ocurre alguna solucion?

Models.py

```
class BlogComentario(models.Model):

post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comentarios')
nombre = models.ForeignKey(Usuario,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
contenido = models.TextField(max_length=500)
publicado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publicado',)
    db_table= "blog_comentario"

def __str__(self):
    return f"comentado por {self.nombre}"
```

Views.py

```
class PostDetalle(DetailView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'blog/post_detalle.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post = BlogPost.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        return context

class PostComentario(DetailView):
    model = BlogComentario
    template_name= "blog/post_detalle.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["comentarios"] = BlogComentario.objects.all()
        return context
```

template

```
    <div class="card-body bg-light" id="comment-box">
    <!-- the comments -->
    {% for comentario in comentarios %}
    <h3><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> {{comentario.nombre}} dice:
        <small> {{comentario.publicado}}</small>
    </h3>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor evita compartir tu codigo en imagen, mejor pasalo por texto

Comment: Ahi lo modifique!

Comment: Podrías especificar cual es el problema?

Comment: No se muestran los comentarios con el FOR del template, el {% for comentario in comentarios %} no esta detectando los comentarios creados

Comment: Intenta agrengando la cláusula `empty` al `for` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty . Si se muestra el mensaje que pusiste en la cláusula, entonces significa que no tienes ningún comentario almacenado en la base de datos